# Barebones example: C# application with a custom msbuild task

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, .net-core, msbuild-task

Microsoft has good [documentation on writing custom build tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/task-writing), but it contains snippets and doesn't give the full picture.

What does a **minimal but complete** project that achieves the following look like?

- Builds an executable that is written in C#
- Executes a build task that is written in C#

A valid example could be a build task that does nothing, but runs, and an application that does nothing except return 0.

If the answer is different for .NET Framework v4.5 **vs** .NET Core 2.0, then it would be good to know what that difference is. I anticipate that there are several *valid* configurations, such as

- Application and build tasks are separate csproj files, **or** a single one.
- Building the tasks into a separate dll **or** not.
- Running the task before/after compiling the application **or** when the solution is loaded **or** not running it automatically at any point, but making it available to batch scripts and on the command line.

So the question is, which configuration is the most minimal and what does it look like?

.

Additional background: The only bit of documentation I've been able to find about *connecting the task to your project* recommends `UsingTask`, which references a DLL that contains the task. This implies having the task in a separate csproj or even solution, and building separately. However, the examples I was able to find on GitHub where people appear to be using custom build tasks do not use this approach. I have, for example, a 3rd-party sln loaded right now where `UsingTask` is nowhere in sight, yet Visual Studio shows and runs a custom build task `.cs` file in the solution explorer underneath one of the projects (even though that `.cs` file is not mentioned anywhere in the project's `.csproj` file!). So it seems to me that `UsingTask` is not the only way to achieve project/task linkage, and probably not the simplest either.

Comment: The .cs file could be included via a wildcard, i.e. <Compile Include="**\*.cs" />

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to do. Running logic on build can be done in targets as well and might not need tasks. Tasks can be defined inline (CodeTaskFactory) or use a pre-existing dll (=> you can't run a task before the assembly is compiled if you really want to use the built assembly to provide tasks)

Comment: If you want to ship a NuGet package that allows to use build tasks, that is a little different story and needs more setup, but easier to use for consumers. I believe your question is a bit too broad.

Comment: The documentation for CodeTaskFactory leads me to think that it uses XML rather than C# for the task, which is not what I'm looking for here.

I'll add some emphasis and make some tweaks to clarify the scope of the question. The key here is "minimal but complete". I have yet to see, in one concise place, an entire csproj (or two?) (and sln?) that one could copy/paste to have a project which builds an executable and runs a custom, local, written-in-C# task. If there are multiple ways to achieve this, then the best answer would be the most minimal without becoming incomplete.